# Images not appearing in Google Chrome

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, numbers

I have an image (with a number in the image name - it's called ad1.jpg). Anyhow, it loads fine on any major browser I tested, yet it never seems to load on Google Chrome for some reason. I saw it once today, but aside from that, it's the old image title that appears instead of the image.

I am 150% sure that the problem is that Google Chrome is not properly reading the image name because of the number. Is there an actual problem with using number in image names using HTML5 standards? If not, does Chrome actually have a problem reading numbers in image names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem, it was because of an 'Ad Blocker' installed on my browser.  It read the word 'ad' and blocked it.  Is it possible that is the problem?

Comment: It's EXACTLY that. As for the word ad, that's the name of my picture. I don't know why the designer called it that (as it's not an ad).

I have Avast on my browser and it has an adblocker (I didn't really know Avast actually had one). But the problem is that it's not an ad, only a picture, unless it's really blocking the pic because is has the word 'ad'? Do you really think so?

Comment: I had the exact same problem with FF a while ago, I called my images ad_##.png .. took me a while to figure out it was the AdBlocker :)

Comment: Just change the name of the image to "pic1.jpg" or something else.

Comment: Now I know! I really thought it was a number issue. But it's not... it's the word 'ad' - thanks for that Adam. It would have taken me a long time to figure that out if it wasn't for you.

Comment: @Jack, yes I could do that... no wait, I should.

Answer (score 1):

If you refresh the page several times work? Clear cookies and cache and try again. Maybe this is problem.

Comment: Nope, it was an adblocker (I rarely use Chrome, and it has an adblocker from Avast... but it might have been, as Adam pointed out, because of the word 'ad' in the picture being blocked by Avast adblocker).

Comment: Interesting. Good job from Adam.

Comment: For sure, but your answer has merits of its own! Not everyone would know to clear the cache (in my case, I knew it wasn't the cache). So it might help others.