# Image not loaded in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, google-chrome

I am trying to load the image from server database through jsp. All browsers are supported but in Google Chrome not supported.

here is my code:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    
    <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://ec2-54-200-73-139.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/retriveimage/view.jsp?carrier_name=ondot" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code as-is worked fine for me in Chrome - I applied a minor edit to your question to make the html into a runnable snippet, and the image specified in that `src` attribute *does* appear.

Comment: @nnnnnn — It doesn't for me. https://www.evernote.com/l/AANgQ_ilzvZBv44x2yInpyG9q-D43V1ViR0

Comment: I think you need to make it public , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768596/how-do-i-show-an-image-from-my-amazon-s3-on-my-website , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975693/amazon-s3-access-image-by-url

Comment: @nnnnnn, Thanks for your response. Still iam getting same problem.

Comment: @PranavCBalan, thanks for your support. for remaining browsers, its works well. only in case of chrome iam getting error.

Comment: @Quentin - Well I can't explain why, but it works for me without me doing anything special.

Comment: @Sateesh2607: why are you responding as if this is your question? Are you also user ccc2607?

Comment: @Sateesh2607 : do you installed adBlocker , then just disable it and check... I hope it will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600182/images-not-appearing-in-google-chrome

Comment: @PranavCBalan, yes

Comment: @PranavCBalan, still same error.

Comment: @Sateesh2607 : clear cookies and cache and try

Answer (score 0):

Once we examine your network call we found that error is some thing like this **'ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING'** so follow the below link it might be help you.

[ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error)

[ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608564/neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-in-chrome-only)

[ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506856/err-incomplete-chunked-encoding-chrome-root-page-load)